# SQL file with multiple statements separated by “;” error

Tags: sql, python-3.7

I am running the code below: The first part of the SQL script creates a table and is ended with a ';' then the second part of the sql creates another table. When the python script is run, it seems to create the tables but then loops through and I get an error:

> pyodbc.Error:(('HY000', '[HY000] Virtual table 'MY_FIRST_TABLE_NAME'
>   already exists. (1000) (SQLExecDirectW)')

My Code:

```
import pyodbc
import getpass
import os
print ("Connecting via ODBC")
windows_password=getpass.getpass('Enter your windows password please')
composite_connection=pyodbc.connect("Driver=my driver;HOST=my host;PORT=my port;UID={0};PWD={1};DOMAIN=my domain;DATASOURCE=my datasource".format(getpass.getuser(),windows_password),autocommit=True)
print ("You are Connected\n")
inputdir = 'C:\\Users\\abc01'
for script in os.listdir(inputdir):
    with open(inputdir+'\\' + 'my_sql_script.sql','r') as inserts:
        sqlScript = inserts.read()
        for statement in sqlScript.split(';'):
            with composite_connection.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute(statement)
    print(script)
composite_connection.close()
>
```

This is the sql:

```
CREATE TABLE DB.Table_1
(
    ORDER_INFO_ID VARCHAR(30),
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR(30),
    ORDER_ID VARCHAR(20),
    MOBILE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20),
    ADD_FIRST_LINE VARCHAR(150),
    POSTCODE_LAST VARCHAR(5)
)
;
CREATE TABLE DB.Table_2
(ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR (30),
MOBILE_NUMBER VARCHAR (30)
)
```

Comment: How should we know what goes wrong? Could you at least share the minimal SQL file triggering the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual tables persist throughout a session.

Your loop executes all queries within the same session, if the first query creates a virtual table, then when the second tries to create the same virtual table you will get the error.

If you want them to operate in different sessions, move the connect and close to inside the inner-most loop

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure how I'd do that, can you show how me with the code above please?

Comment: Depends whether you want one session per file, per query, or per folder etc... just move where you call connect and open into the respective loops